# How to remove the namespace of SOAPHeaderElement using PHP

Tags: php, soap

So basically I want the SOAP header to be like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xfire.super8.com/CrsService" xmlns:ns2="http://www.gzjhotel.com:9999/iPegasus/services/CrsService?wsdl">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <AuthenticationToken>
      <Username>xxx</Username>
      <Password>xxx</Password>
    </AuthenticationToken>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getHotelList>
      <ns1:city>GZ</ns1:city>
    </ns1:getHotelList>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

But instead, now I have this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://xfire.super8.com/CrsService" xmlns:ns2="http://www.gzjhotel.com:9999/iPegasus/services/CrsService?wsdl">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
     <ns2:AuthenticationToken SOAP-ENV:actor="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/actor/next">
        <Username>xxx</Username>
        <Password>xxx</Password>
    </ns2:AuthenticationToken>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:getHotelList>
      <ns1:city>GZ</ns1:city>
    </ns1:getHotelList>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is the php code that I'm currently using:

```html
$headerParam = [
   'Username' => $username,
   'Password' => $password,
];
$client = new \SoapClient($requestUrl, ['trace' => true]);
$authvalues = new \SoapVar($headerParam, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header = new \SoapHeader($requestUrl, 'AuthenticationToken', $authvalues, 
false, SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
$r = $client->getHotelList(['city' => 'GZ']);
```

Where have I gone wrong? I seems unable to construct the header properly.

Comment: Please add the actual code / error here.

Comment: I have already corrected, please check it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it, by using XSD_ANYXML

```
        $headerParam = "<AuthenticationToken><Username>$username</Username><Password>$password</Password></AuthenticationToken>";
        $client = new \SoapClient($requestUrl, ['trace' => true]);
        $authvalues = new \SoapVar($headerParam, XSD_ANYXML);
        $header = new \SoapHeader($requestUrl, 'AuthenticationToken', $authvalues, false, SOAP_ACTOR_NEXT);
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
```

Thanks  to :[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609718/php-soapclient-how-to-structure-soap-header)